# Only disable scrolling to onclick href element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, stoppropagation

I've got some elements on a page with a accordion/tab UI thing behind it, and when a user clicks one, it opens and also scrolls it to the top of the page due to the anchor in the `href`. I want to stop that jumping behavior *only*.
This is an example of such an element;

```
<a class="data switch" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="trigger" href="#description" id="tab-label-description-title">
More info
</a>
```

Because this element is tied up in all kinds of CMS and UIX related things I cannot change the `href` value as most answers to similar questions suggest.

So I tried with JavaScript/jQuery something like this;

```
$('.data.switch').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This does stop the jumping to the element, but it also stops everything else making the element not functional at all. So my question is; is there some sort of variant of `stopPropagation` action that only disables jumping to an anchor element?

**edit** I'm thinking aloud here; like `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault` stops all bubbling actions, isn't there a way to specify just the scrolling? Or maybe a workaround where onclick it reads thew current scrollposition and forces to stay at that position (though this feels very hacky)..?

Comment: Try using `e.preventDefault()` instead. If that doesn't work then we need to see a working example, including the HTML and JS which creates the accordion

Comment: I tried e.preventDefault too. I can't make an example easily because of mentioned libraries/cms/elements working all together to create this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve you result by doing follow things

In you **HTML** code add `id` tag like

```
<a class="data switch" id="dataSwitch" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="trigger" href="#description" id="tab-label-description-title">
    More info
</a>
```

and in your **jquery** use document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataSwitch').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is identical to what the OP already has, aside from the arrow function and id selector which won't have any noticeable effect on the outcome.

Comment: That was what I was going to say, yes. For posterity I did try it with an ID but there is no difference in behaviour.